# iOS How to add STATIC UITableView and another view to the same view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, storyboard

When I create a static table view and put it in a normal view controller, I get an error which says that static table views must be in UITableViewController's.

What I want is a view on the iPad which has a static table view which takes up most of the screen, but a standard UIView under it which always stays visible and has a couple of labels which I update based on content in the table view.

Is there a way to use a UITableViewController and have the tableView not be full screen so that I can add a subview to it in a Storyboard?

If no, can it be done in code?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer is to create a custom container controller.

For instance, you can have a static table view inside a nav controller.  So, you need to create a container class, like a nav controller or whatever yours is, and add the static table view controller to that.

Answer (score 6):

What you need is a regular `UITableViewController` (so you get all the static cell behavior) and then your view as a subview of the table view, but managed such that it always sticks to the bottom of the screen. Apple demonstrated this as WWDC. Here's what I do (in my example, I have a `UIDatePicker` that I always want anchored at the bottom):

In `viewDidLoad`, create your view and add it as a subview of the table view. Place it at the bottom of the table view.

```
[self.tableView addSubview:self.datePicker];
[self updateDatePickerBounds];
```

Implement `scrollViewDidScroll` so that you can force your view to the bottom of the screen ever time the table view scrolls:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Keep the date picker floating above the table view, anchored to the bottom of the view
    [self updateDatePickerBounds];
}
```

And then implement a function that positions your view correctly:

```
- (void) updateDatePickerBounds
{
    // Keep the date picker floating above the table view, anchored at the bottom
    CGRect tableBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    CGRect pickerFrame = self.datePicker.frame;
    pickerFrame = CGRectMake(tableBounds.origin.x,
                             tableBounds.origin.y + CGRectGetHeight(tableBounds) - CGRectGetHeight(pickerFrame),
                             tableBounds.size.width,
                             pickerFrame.size.height);
    self.datePicker.frame = pickerFrame;
}
```

Finally, if you don't want your table view going under your bottom view, just set the table view's `contentInset` to match the height of your view.

I also call my `updateDatePickerBounds` method from `viewWillAppear`. I forget why I had to do that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about - a UITableViewController set up with static cells. You can float a view above the table view using the technique I described. I've done it several times.

Comment: UPDATE: Actually, the better place to call updateDatePickerBounds is in viewDidLayoutSubviews. Then you don't need to override scrollViewDidScroll. viewDidLayoutSubviews is also called during device rotation, so things will get updated in that case as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it works, but you may want to try this approach too:

1. Create a UIViewController, e.g. BaseViewController (both a class and in Storyboard)
2. Create a UITableViewController e.g. MyStaticTableViewController (only in Storyboard and add an identifier to it)
3. In Storyboard, add an instance of UIView with appropriate dimensions to your BaseViewcontroller, e.g. myStaticTableView.
4. Programmatically, add the view of MyStaticTableViewController to myStaticTableView.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect using `UITableViewController` and a static `UITableView`. Create the view you want at the bottom of the table and set the `tableFooterView` property on `UITableView` to be that view. This can be done by dragging a `UIView` object out of the library and adding it to the bottom of the table view (you'll notice the bottom area highlight in blue to know you're doing it correctly). You may have to adjust the content insets to get it to display how you want.

Comment: The footer is only visible when you are at the bottom of the table though, correct?  I need this view to be visible at all times.

Comment: Great solution! You can add a normal UIView before or after a table view section which is basically the same as integrating it the other way round and it actually works.

Answer (score 1):

Static cell TableViews must be of type UITableViewController, but you can achieve the same effect by using a ViewController with a TableView (or 2) and take care of the cellForRowAtIndexPath method yourself for the TV you want to be "Static Cell".  Just switch the IndexPath.section and .row and build the cell the way you want it.  More coding sure, but you get the same effect and with more flexibility if you don't want to do it Apple's Static Cell way.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it is a LOT of rows so I'm trying to find a better way!